# How We Can Break a String in Wso2esb using Xpath

Tags: xpath, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I wish to break a string in wso2esb using xpath
my input like this

```
<property name="Message" value="assetname:ups,assetcode:452chi,assetid:548935,assetvalue:215" scope="default"/>
```

i need break in same property using xpath
i need like this

```
assetname:ups
assetcode=452chi
assetid=54895
assetvalue=215
```

for this i tried with tokenize function but wso2esb showing errors
my configure file

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Xpathcheck" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="max" value="1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="min" value="1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="MessageText" expression="fn:concat('Assetid:',get-property('min'),',','Assetname:',get-property('max'))" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="Tokenize" expression="fn:tokenize(get-property('Messagetext'),',')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <log>
            <property name="MessageText" expression="get-property('MessageText')"/>
            <property name="Tokenize" expression="get-property('Tokenize')"/>
         </log>
               </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
   </target>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

But its throwing errors like this u have any idea for this i need store this in Db table as a one field which look like separate lines
error is

```
ERROR - SynapseXPath Evaluation of the XPath expression fn:tokenize(get-property('Messagetext'),',') resulted in an error
org.jaxen.UnresolvableException: No Such Function tokenize
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tokenize is a function comes with XPath 2.0. To enable XPath 2.0 functions uncomment the following entry in the synapse.properties file which is located at $ESB_HOME/repository/conf directory

```
synapse.xpath.dom.failover.enabled=true
```

then you have to specify the mediator as follows,

```
<property name="Message" value="a,b,c,d,e" scope="default"/>
         <property xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" name="Tokenize" expression="fn:tokenize(syn:get-property('Message'),',')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this can be done through XPath, XPath is to navigate elements in an XML. You can do this by using a script mediator and write a JS to break the property values. 
use the following to access the ESB params from the script mediator

```
<script language="js"> var test_param = mc.getProperty('Message')
```

Use the following to retrieve the params within the script mediator back to the ESB

```
mc.setProperty("param1",var1)
mc.setProperty("param2",var2)
```

Use the javascript to carry out the required string manupulations

Comment: Thanx for quick replay .can we append the value in one property like an array can we able to create array in wso2esb

Comment: You can create such an array through the script mediator which can then be accessed by the ESB.

Comment: thanx again..k i will try basically i am from oracle soa so i dont know much more about javascript

Comment: If you encounter any error please post as a question someone from the community would be able to help you out.