# Can we pass parameters to main sequence url in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am calling main sequence from `localhost:8280` .

I want to pass parameters to main sequence like `

> localhost:8280 ?book = "math "

Please suggest if this is feasible to pass parameters in main sequence URL or we need to use Rest API for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract such parameters like this :

```
<property name="PARAM1"
expression="tokenize(substring-after(syn:get-property('To'),'param1='),'&')"
scope="default"
type="STRING"/>

<property name="PARAM1"
expression="tokenize(substring-after(syn:get-property('To'),'param2='),'&')"
scope="default"
type="STRING"/>
```

Comment: -Michel : I am getting below errors while using above

[2014-05-20 10:04:26,212] ERROR - SynapseXPath Evaluation of the XPath expression tokenize(substring-after(syn:get-property('To'),'book='),'&') resulted in an error
org.jaxen.UnresolvableException: No Such Function tokenize

Comment: To use tokenize function you need to enable Xpath 2. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586688/how-we-can-break-a-string-in-wso2esb-using-xpath