# Xpath 2.0 functions support in WSO2 ESB

Tags: xml, function, xpath, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I am trying to use tokenize xpath fn in my wso2 esb proxy service. 
I need to split my input string based on certain condition.

But I got the following error,

```sh
SynapseXPath Evaluation of the XPath expression fn:tokenize(//SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/m:subscribe/m:subscribe/m1:filter/m1:messageContent, ' and ') resulted in an error
org.jaxen.UnresolvableException: No Such Function {http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions}:tokenize.
```

Following few blogs I have uncommented xpath 2.0 in synapse properties file in 
`$ESB_HOME/repository/conf` and rebooted ESB, still I got the same error.

Any inputs on this will be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what version of the ESB are you using? I have not been able to reproduce this problem on 4.8.1 and 5.0.0

Comment: I am using 5.0 and now the issue got resolved. 
There was some issue with installation I believe, got errors in OSGi bundle as well.
I have installed a fresh copy and now it is working as expected.
Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use XPath 2.0 functions in WSO2EI, you'll need to do two things.

1. activate `synapse.xpath.dom.failover.enabled=true` in `<ESB_HOME>/repository/conf/synapse.properties`
2. indicate explicitly the *namespace* for `fn`. For instance, instead of

```xml
<property name="numbers" expression="fn:tokenize($ctx:phone_numbers, ';')"/>
```

you should say

```xml
<property name="numbers" expression="fn:tokenize($ctx:phone_numbers, ';')" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"/>
```

Tested successfully on wso2ei 6.5.0

PS: there's also a [split_to_element](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/Split-to-elements+Function) function but I never managed to make it work properly

Comment: This worked for WSO2 MI 4.2.0 as well.

Answer (score -1):

You may follow [1] and [2].

[1] http://wso2logs.blogspot.com/2015/05/error-when-executing-xpath-20-functions.html

[2] [How We Can Break a String in Wso2esb using Xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586688/how-we-can-break-a-string-in-wso2esb-using-xpath)